# Mouse monitoring and distance

Tags: java, multithreading, background, mouse

Good Evening,

I just had an idea to create a program which monitors the mouse and increments the distance you do with you mouse. With that you could make statistics and send them to an online data base which would be created on a website.

Therefore, i would like to know how i could do a program, put it in the background and which monitors the mouse.
Which language would be the best ? I was thinking of doing it in java because it is a language  that i know pretty well and which is portable to any machine.

Thanks in advance for your advice and tips

Kuna,

Comment: IRC, AWT Toolkit only listen to event happening in AWT and AWT Robot only allows moving mouse while in the background, so I think you may need to use native code.

Comment: Hmmmm ok, For example it would monitor the mouse even if you are in a game or whatever if that wasn't clear.
Thanks for your quick response